# Return one dimension of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

How would I only return one dimension of an array, while ignoring the other?

Such as:

```
int map[4][8];

int MapManager::getMapX(int x)
{
    return map[x];
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement `getRow` and `getCol`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the other answers here return an actual array (pointers are not arrays), I thought I might show how to really return an array. Or the closest thing possible, which is a reference to an array.

```
typedef int row_type[8];

row_type& MapManager::getMapX(int x) {
    return map[x];
}
```

> What's the point of this? The pointer works the same!

No, it doesn't. The pointer loses type information, namely, *the size*. You can make [`begin()` and `end()` functions](http://ideone.com/ruKX3) work with arrays, but you can't with pointers:

```
// pointer version
int* MapManager::getMapX_ptr(int x) {
    return map[x];
}

row_type& row = getMapX(0);
// row is of type int(&)[8]
// notice the size is not lost in the type!
std::sort(begin(row), end(row));
// compiles fine! end() correctly finds the end of the row

int* ptr = getMapX_ptr(0);
// notice how ptr has no size information at all
std::sort(begin(ptr), end(ptr));
// can't possible be made to work!
```

You can't write `end` for `int*`.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T(&arr)[N]) {
    return &arr[0] + N;
}

template <typename T>
T* end(T* ptr) {
    // what here?
    // guess?
    // pick a random number?
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The return type should be `int*` or `int[]`, not `int`:

```
int* MapManager::getMapX(int x) {
    return map[x];
}
```

Other than that, you are fine.

Answer (score 5):

With a 2 dimensional array you will only be able to directly return a one dimensional array for the inner array by converting to a pointer, such as

```
int map[4][8];

int* MapManager::getMapX(int x)
{
    return map[x];
}
```

For the other 'dimension', you will need to have another external array to copy to:

```
int* MapManager::getMapY(int y, int *outArray, int numElements)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
      outArray[i] = map[i][y];
   }
}
```

This array needs to be allocated with the correct size. (8 in this case).

The reason for this is that the array elements for the y 'column' are not contiguous in memory, but spread across several arrays (which are the 'x' rows).  C arrays rely on this contiguous concept for accessing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a special class that provides a strided view of an array.  That is to say, it skips over values.  Here's the beginnings of something like that:

```
template<typename T>
class StridedView
{
public:
    StridedView(T * b, int stride, int count)
        :begin_(b), stride_(stride), count_(count)
    {}

    template<int N>
    StridedView(T (&arr)[N])
        :begin_(arr), stride_(1), count_(N)
    {}

    T & operator[](int index)
    {
        return *(begin_ + index * stride_);
    }

    const T & operator[](int index) const
    {
        return *(begin_ + index * stride_);
    }

    int size() const { return count_; }
private:
    T * begin_;
    int stride_;
    int count_;
};
```

Then you could have functions that can get you a row or a column as appropriate:

```
template<typename T, int R, int C>
StridedView<T> GetRow(T (&arr)[R][C], int row)
{
    T * begin = (*arr) + (row * C);
    return StridedView<T>(begin, 1, C);
}

template<typename T, int R, int C>
StridedView<T> GetColumn(T (&arr)[R][C], int column)
{
    T * begin = (*arr) + column;
    return StridedView<T>(begin, C, R);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/xflPs)